# Does the ZPM regenerate power, or did season 3 have a continuity error?

Tags: stargate, continuity, stargate-atlantis, zero-point-module

In Season 3,

- Episode 8 "McKay and Mrs. Miller", the team completely drains Atlantis' only ZPM.
- Episode 9 takes place off-world.
- Episode 10 shows a fully functioning Atlantis (which is turned over the Lanteans).

The canon shows no ability to regenerate a depleted ZPM so that really leaves continuity error or number of much less likely reasons that Atlantis ends up with a fully functioning ZPM.

Where did their operational ZPM come from?

Comment: i cant remeber these episodes 100% but i thought the lanteans (well the replicators) bring new ZPMS. i know the replicators also have like unlimited zpms, as the steal them from them lol.

Comment: Either that, or they aired out of order?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a continuity error: the Lanteans had a ZPM on their ship, and they used that to power Atlantis.

Early in the episode, McKay points out the problem when introducing the new Gate Bridge:

> **McKay:** So, I’m in Atlantis and I need to get to Earth. What do I do? Since we no longer have access to a ZedP.M. -- due to unforeseeable circumstances -- my only option would be to call the Daedalus and spend the next three weeks twiddling my thumbs waiting to get back home.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Stargate: Atlantis* Season 3 Episode 10: "The Return: Part 1"](https://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s3/transcripts/310.shtml)</sub></sup>

Sheppard confirms that the evacuation (for want of a better word) is courtesy of a ZPM from the Lanteans (emphasis mine):

> **Sheppard:** Well, we are way ahead of schedule, ready to head out at 0800. Daedalus is gonna take most of the gear. **People and our odds and ends will make their way through the Stargate, thanks to the Ancients' new ZeeP.M.**
>
> <sup><sub>[*Stargate: Atlantis* Season 3 Episode 10: "The Return: Part 1"](https://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s3/transcripts/310.shtml)</sub></sup>

As to how Atlantis is even running after the ZPM is depleted in "McKay and Mrs. Miller", it was established as far back as season 1 that they can power the city (to a limited degree), and even dial out within the Pegasus galaxy, using naquadah generators:

> **Beckett:** What about our own power generators?
>
> **McKay:** We're working on that, but even with our most advanced naqahdah power generators, the equations are coming up far short.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Sumner:** Can we use the Stargate?
>
> **McKay:** There's nowhere near enough power to open a wormhole back to Earth.
>
> **Sheppard:** Maybe somewhere in this galaxy.
>
> **McKay:** That's relatively easy.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Stargate: Atlantis* Season 1 Episode 1: "Rising: Part 1"](https://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s1/transcripts/101.shtml)</sub></sup>

Comment: Ah, OK either the Lanteans in the Aurora or the Replicators that kick their ass would have supplied one.  Since the Replicators could have fully powered Atlantis with 3 ZPMs and the SGA team ends up with just one, I assume it is the Lanteans who provide the single replacement.  Too bad they were exterminated.

Comment: Personally, I can't believe Sheppard or McKay didn't think of doing what Todd did - steal the Replicators' ZPMs before blowing the place. But... that was after this episode, so I digress.

Comment: IIRC the Lanteans supplied one ZPM that had been powering their ship before the Replicators arrived and took over. Then they were nice enough to repair primary systems *and* bring Atlantis up to 3 ZPM. After regaining control of the city they only got to keep *one* of the ZPM with Earth and one of the BC304s getting the other two to defend against the Ori.